# Knowing that $\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha)=-\frac{1}{3}$ and $\tan \alpha > 0$, find the exact value of $\tan \alpha$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

First I tried to solve for $\alpha$:

$$\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha)=-\frac{1}{3} \Leftrightarrow \alpha = \arccos(-\frac{1}{3})+2k\pi-\frac{3\pi}{2} \lor \alpha = -\arccos(-\frac{1}{3})+2k\pi-\frac{3\pi}{2}$$

Then I put $\tan(\arccos(-\frac{1}{3})-\frac{3\pi}{2})$ and $\tan(-\arccos(-\frac{1}{3})-\frac{3\pi}{2})$ in the calculator and $\tan(\arccos(-\frac{1}{3})-\frac{3\pi}{2})$ was positive while the other was negative, so I assumed the positive one was the correct expression.

But I don't know how to simplify it to get the exact value. My book says the solution is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: your first equation gives $\sin (\alpha)\,=\,\frac{1}{3}$ which can be easily solved to get $\tan(\alpha)\,=\,\frac{\sqrt2}{4}$

$$\cos(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha)\,=\,-\sin(\alpha)$$

Comment: **Formatting tip:** When entering trig functions, notice that adding ` \ ` before the functions looks much better, 
see: `$sin x$` gives $sin x$ whereas `$\sin x$` gives $\sin x$. The same goes in the case of log functions, see: 
`$\log x$` and `$\ln x$` give $\log x$ and $\ln x$ and look better, as opposed to `$log x$` and `$ln x$` which 
give $log x$ and $ln x$.

Answer (score 3):

$\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+a\right)=\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\cos(a)-\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\sin(a)=-\sin(a)=-\frac{1}{3}=>\sin(a)=\frac{1}{3}$

$\cos(a)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{a}}=\sqrt{1-\frac19}=\sqrt{\frac89}$

$\tan(a)=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\sqrt{\frac89}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}=\boxed{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}}$

Comment: Why $\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\cos(a)-\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)\sin(a)=-\sin(a)$ and not $= \sin(\alpha)$? $-\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2})=1$, isn't it?